# put the file into an array in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a txt file, and put it into an char array. But can I read different files which contain different length of characters and put them into an array. Can I create a dynamic array to contain unknown length of characters.

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: use std::vector, std::string and std::getline
i made an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file of unknown size into a dynamics data structure like:

`std::vector` More info [*here*](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-16-an-introduction-to-stdvector/).

Alternatively, you can use `new` to allocate a dynamic memory. However, vectors are more convenient at least to me :).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::vector<std::string> content;

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    std::cout << "bad argument" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }


  std::string file_name (argv[1]);
  std::ifstream file(file_name);

  if (!file)
  {
    std::cout << "can't open file" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }

  std::string line = "";
  while (std::getline(file, line))
  {
    content.push_back(line);
    line = "";
  }

  for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = content.begin(); it != content.end(); ++it)
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

here is a solution using std::vectors and std::string

the programm takes a file name as first parameter, opens it, read it line by line

each line is written in the vector

then you can display your vector as i did at the end of the function

EDIT: because C++11 is the new standars, the program use C++11 then you have to compile it using c++11 (`g++ -std=c++11` if you use g++)

I just tested it it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There may be library routines available which give you the size of the file without reading the contents of the file.  In that case you could get the size and allocate a full-sized buffer, and suck in the whole file at once [if your buffer is a simple char array, don't forget to add one and put in the trailing nullchar].

Answer (score -3):

The best way is use of `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` just like it was an old C program. If you try to use a `std::vector` you will choke approaching maximum RAM as `realloc()` can grow and shrink in place (grow is contingent on heap while shrink is guaranteed to work) while `std::vector` cannot do so.

In particular:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
// TODO perhaps you want an auto-management class for this tuple.
// I'm not about to type up the whole auto_ptr, shared_ptr, etc.
// Mostly you don't do this enough to have to worry too hard.
std::tuple<char *, size_t> getarray(std::istream &input)
{
    size_t fsize = 0;
    size_t asize = 0;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t terminator = (size_t)-1;
    char *buf = malloc(asize = 8192);
    if (!buf) throw std::bad_alloc();
    char *btmp;
    char shift = 1;
    do {
        try {
           input.read(buf + offset, asize - fsize);
        } catch (...) {
            free(buf);
            throw;
        }
        if (input.gcount == 0) {
            btmp = realloc(buf, bufsize);
            if (btmp) buf = btmp;
            return std::tuple<char *, size_t>(buf, fsize);
        }
        offset += input.gcount;
        fsize += offset;
        if (fsize == asize) {
            if (shift) {
                 if ((asize << 1) == 0)
                     shift = 0;
                 else {
                     btmp = realloc(buf, asize << 1);
                     if (!btmp)
                         shift = 0;
                     else {
                         asize <<= 1;
                         buf = btmp;
                     }
                 }
                 if (!shift) {
                     btmp = realloc(buf, asize += 8192);
                     if (!btmp) {
                         free(buf);
                         throw std::bad_alloc();
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
    } while (terminator - offset > fsize);
    free(buf);
    // Or perhaps something suitable.
    throw "File too big to fit in size_t";
}
```

Comment: Some dive bomber doesn't like saving a lot of RAM.

Comment: To be honest this is a very complex and error prone method. I could write the equivalent in about 3 lines using standard library components.

Comment: @Galik: Well if you know your file is small enough.

Comment: `malloc(asize == 8192)`... wat?